# ggeffects: confidence interval for non-linear model

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd to plot the confidence interval for non-linear models using ggeffects package. In my case:

```
#Packages
library(ggplot2) 
library(minpack.lm)  
library(ggeffects)
library(dplyr)

# My dataset
coleo<- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/PEN-533/master/coleo-infest-tree.csv")
coleo$DL<-as.numeric(coleo$DL)
coleo$V<-as.numeric(coleo$V)

# My model
m.c.coleo<-nlsLM(V ~ b1 + b2 * I(DL^b3), start = list(b1 = 0.2164, b2 = 1.6264, b3 = 1), data = coleo)
summary(m.c.coleo)

# My plot
ggpredict(m.c.coleo, terms = "DL [all]") %>% plot(add.data = TRUE)
```

[image: myplot]

The output plot doesn't have a confidence interval and normally the package makes it.

Please, any help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is due to the fact that `ggpredict` uses the generic `predict` function, and `predict.nls` does not produce standard errors. From the docs for `ggpredict`:

> `ggpredict()` uses `predict()` for generating predictions

And the docs for `stats:::predict.nls` state:

> **se.fit**    A logical value indicating if the standard errors of the predictions should be calculated. Defaults to FALSE. At present this argument is ignored.

The plot that `ggpredict` makes for your model seems a bit odd anyway. If you look at the data, there are only 5 discrete values of `DL` along the x axis:

```r
plot(coleo$DL, coleo$V)
```

[image]

To make a plot which includes the original points, the nls regression line and a confidence interval for the regression line, you could create one yourself in ggplot. The standard error of the mean at each of the discrete values of `DL` can be approximated by the standard deviation divided by the square root of the number of points at that x value. A smooth band representing the 95% confidence interval can then be constructed by interpolation:

```r
plot_df <- data.frame(
  DL = seq(0, 1, 0.01),
  V = predict(m.c.coleo, newdata = list(DL = seq(0, 1, 0.01))),
  se = 1.96 * summary(m.c.coleo)$sigma / sqrt(approx(sort(unique(coleo$DL)), 
       table(coleo$DL), xout = seq(0, 1, 0.01))$y)
)

ggplot(coleo, aes(DL, V)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_light() +
  geom_ribbon(data = plot_df, aes(ymin = V - se, ymax = V + se),
              alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_line(data = plot_df)
```

[image]